# Is is possible to record voice from the microphone in Decentraland?

Tags: typescript, try-catch, microphone, voice, decentraland

I am trying to catch the voice from micrpphone in Decentraland  but not able to do it but I am able to convert any mp3 to text.
If Some has work on decentraland  for capturing the voice from microphone.

1.Is is possible to record voice from the microphone in Decentraland ?
2. Is there some alternative way to achieve this like using a nodejs library that integrates with the Decentraland SDK ?

I am expecting to resolve this above issue

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with DCL since 2019-

External import mics will work to talk to other players but, in my experience, you can't record your audio directly in-game without a third-party app.

Most high-quality game footage or NPC scenes with audio you may have seen were most likely filmed directly within the team's unity builder and/or exported specifically and edited further with video editing software.

The best practice for porting anything in (streams, audio, video etc.) is through a third-party like OBS which can be directly integrated into Decentraland. If you ask a dev on the team they would reccomend this too (from my experience).